# Show that $f$ defined by $f(t,x)=|\sin(x)|+t$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition on the whole $tx-$ plane

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Show that $f$ defined by $f(t,x)=|\sin(x)|+t$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition on the whole $tx-$ plane with respect to its second argument, but $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ does not existe when $x=0$. What fact does this ilustrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|f(t,x)-f(s,y)|=|t-s+|\sin (x)| -|\sin (y)|| \leq |t-s|+| |\sin (x)| -|\sin (y)|| \leq |t-s|+ |\sin(x) -\sin (y)| \leq |t-s|+|x-y|$ by Mean Value Theorem.
Hence $|f(t,x)-f(s,y)| \leq 2 ||((t,x) -(s,y)||$ where ||.|| is the usual norm on $\mathbb R^{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

note that $$|\sin(x)+1|\le |\sin(x)|+1\le 1+1=2$$
i have used the triangle inequality $$|a+b|\le |a|+|b|$$ and that $$|\sin(x)|\le 1$$ for all real $x$
and $$|\sin(x)|$$ has no derivative at $$x=0$$ since $$\frac{f(t,0)-f(t,0)}{h}=\frac{|h|}{h}$$ doesn't exist for $h$ tends to zero

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, I already corrected it ... could you explain a little more about how I raise it please!

Comment: What is the condition you should verify? because as I understood it to be a function, it was necessary to verify $||f(x)-f(y)||\leq K||x-y||,\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ siendo $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$

Comment: as you have written in your question a Lipschitz constant exists but $$\frac{\partial f(0,t)}{\partial x}$$ exits not

Comment: But what does uniform Lipschitz condition mean? and, Apologize and what relationship exists between the derivative does not exist and the fact that there is that constant Lipschitz?